# Which statistic test should I use to see which symptoms contribute more to the diagnostic?

Tags: spss

I have a SPSS data set with 70 respondents with disease and 70 control respondents  without disease. I also have a list of 18 symptoms that they could have. Is there a way to ascertain which symptoms contribute more to the diagnostic? Which statistc test should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Simple `logistic regression` can be used when the outcome variable is binary. You can code having and not having a disease as 1 and 0 and the 18 symptoms will be your predictor variables. If you're planning to use SPSS, perhaps you might find [this](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/whatstat/whatstat.htm#simplog) useful

Comment: With 18 features and 140 datapoints that seems to be quite likely to result in some overfitting. Also, using this to decide what to include in the model based on some of the things people sometimes use (e.g. p <x) tends to be a bad idea.

Comment: And what entrance method should I use?

Comment: If there is overfitting you could use logistic regression with the lasso, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212613/use-lasso-logistic-regression-to-analyze-binary-data